# How to do the token exchange impersonation in Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I’m trying to impersonate a user using the token exchange functionality but I always get the error that the client is not allowed to exchange.

This is the request I’m doing using the WebFlux WebClient:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange");
    formData.add("requested_token_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token");
    formData.add("client_id", keycloakClientId);
    formData.add("requested_subject", userId);
    formData.add("subject_token", token);
    return WebClient.create()
        .post()
        .uri(authServerUrl + "/realms/" + authServerRealm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
        .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(AccessTokenResponse.class));
```

The response I get is this one:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Client not allowed to exchange"}
```

How do I get the token above to be exchanged:

```
KeycloakBuilder.builder()
          .serverUrl(authServerUrl)
          .realm(authServerRealm)
          .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
          .username(keycloakAdminUsername)
          .password(keycloakAdminPassword)
          .clientId(keycloakClientId)
          .build();
```

What I am doing wrong? Why does the client need to be allowed to exchange since this impersonation and not client token exchange. Does the client need to be confidential for this to be done?

Comment: Hi, have you looked at this. 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#impersonation
Perhaps its a keycloak config problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chris' answer, I also realized that I had to do an additional step: Client -> Service account roles → Client roles → in the dropdown select ‘Realm management’ and assign Impersonation role. I tried this after I installed Keycloak with fine grained permissions as Chris indicated, and following the Keycloak documentation (which sucks btw) https://www.keycloak.org/docs/15.0/securing_apps/index.html#_token-exchange

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant permission (on the target client) to allow `keycloakClientId` to mint a token for the target client.

7.1.1 in the docs:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#internal-token-to-internal-token-exchange

You will also need to start keycloak with the following flags, so that you enable fine grained permissions:

`-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled`